# Express return error without exiting in response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I wrote a resource, to which a user can send data. If the data does not validate (validation returns `false`), I need to send an error 500 status code to the client, but the problem is, that when I use `res.status(500)`, the program exits
and I just want to cancel this request with an error to the client, not stopping the program...

```
function formHandler(req, res, next) {
    let isValid = validate(fields.token)
    if (!isValid) {
        res.status(500).send({ error: 'invalid!' })
    }
```

Comment: You might want a return after that line, or your code will continue and do stuff it's not meant to in error state.

Comment: Please add more code. I think `res` is not defined in that scope

Comment: @Keith - what do you mean , can you provide example ?

Comment: @FarhanYaseen done please see

Comment: @shopiaT  Posted an example, ps. In a way I'm assuming this is the problem, the thing is you don't provide what code comes next, or even if your using an else block.  Or more importantly any error message node might be giving..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note, doing `res.status(500).send({ error: 'invalid!' })` will not terminate the current function..

So ->

```
function formHandler(req, res, next) {
  let isValid = validate(fields.token)
  if (!isValid) {
    res.status(500).send({ error: 'invalid!' })
  }
  //so the code below will even run in invalid state
  res.send("this piece of code will run no matter what");
```

You could either call return, or use an else block.. eg.

```
function formHandler(req, res, next) {
  let isValid = validate(fields.token)
  if (!isValid) {
    res.status(500).send({ error: 'invalid!' });
    return;
  }
  res.send("this piece of code will only run if isValid");
```

Doing a second `res.send` again is most likely giving you the error, as the first `res.send` would have closed the connection..